# Understanding concept of ArcGIS for Flex?

Tags: raster, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, topography

I am a complete newbie to GIS.

I am trying to download topographic data from a website that displays a map that can be zoomed in and out.  The website is setup with:

> This application is using ArcGIS API for Flex version 2.3.1.  Build
>   date 2011-04-26.

I don't understand how the topo data is setup on the server, is this vector data or raster? I can zoom to the most detailed level and get individual 256x256 .jpg tiles but that can't be how the data is setup on the server because that would mean hundreds or thousands of tiles for each zoom layer. I can get very large .gdb files but they don't seem to contain the correct set of files because they won't open in ArcMap.

Comment: [ArcGIS for Flex](https://developers.arcgis.com/flex/guide/guide.htm) is a platform for designing web viewers for GIS data. That data might be either in vector or raster format. Unless there is a link to download the original data on the website, you can only get it by emailing the owner and requesting it.

Comment: Thanks Erica, I emailed the site owners and they said they would be happy to give me the data but they didn't know how to give me the data because they hired a contractor to setup the website several years ago and they don't understand the software or which files to give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/flex-viewer/

You can find a lot of the answers to your questions through that link. On the right of the page you will see different subjects that cover the basics of what Flex is and what you can use it for.

Comment: Thanks, after reading through the information at the link above, it does seem as if the data for the topo map actually is hundreds or thousands of individual .jpg files on the server as a "WebTiledLayer". Now, I need to figure out how to put the individual tiles together in a format that will work with Garmin GPS.

Comment: You are welcome user1892770. I'm not sure about the Garmin GPS question. What are the acceptable file formats for the GPS?

Comment: Garmin generally uses .img files, but I need to learn more, for example, if a Garmin map covers a large area, is that map made up of more than one .img file, etc.